# Can a known quantum state be cloned?

Tags: quantum-information, hilbert-space, quantum-computer, unitarity

According to the [No-cloning theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem), it is impossible to create a clone of unknown quantum state. But how to clone a known quantum state

$$\lvert\psi\rangle=\alpha\lvert0\rangle + \beta\lvert1\rangle~?$$

Answer (score 1):

Knowing a quantum state means that you know the coefficients, in your case $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can produce a state that you have a classical description of. It's just not normally called cloning.

There are many ways you could go about producing the state, using a fixed gate set. For example, you could apply techniques from [the Solovay-Kitaev algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505030) to do it approximately and efficiently.